# Why is my DNA below the ladder?

Tags: molecular-genetics

I have run a gradient PCR.. and band 6 after the ladder is clearly the brightest. But all bands appear below the ladder. What does that mean? It is extracted mDNA that was loaded.

Thank you in advance!

[image: enter image description here](https://i.stack.i![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below the ladder means primer dimer.  You have no product.

Comment: Thank you! That explains it. I will try deciding primer amounts and hope for the best!

Comment: In my experience, altering primer concentration won't do anything.  I'd rethink the annealing temp, maybe try a more robust Taq, double-check the quality of your input DNA, and double-check that you have the right primers, and that they actually should make a product.